# Enable diagnostics in Azure SQL Database using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-sql-database

[image]

How can I enable diagnostics in Azure SQL Database using PowerShell?

I am creating the database using Powershell & same time after creating DB, I want to enable Diagnostic logs with Retention days as 1

Any help, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can use PowerShell command `Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting` to enable it, here is my script:

```
$storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName sql -Name jasondisk321
$storageid = $storage.id
$resoure = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains "sql"
$id = $resoure.ResourceId
PS C:\windows\system32> Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $id -StorageAccountId $storageid -RetentionEnabled $true -RetentionInDays "1" -Enabled $true


StorageAccountId : /subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx/resourceGroups/sql/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/jasondisk321
ServiceBusRuleId :
Metrics          : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.MetricSettings}
Logs             : {}
WorkspaceId      :
Id               : /subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx/resourcegroups/sql/providers/microsoft.sql/servers/jason321/databases/jasonsql/providers/microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/service
Name             : service
Type             :
Location         :
Tags             :
```